# Edit Feature in UITableView created using UIViewController

Tags: uitableview

I have created table using UIViewController (instead of UITableViewController) and keeping UITableView as its property.
I have implemented necessary methods of DataSource and Delegate protocols. But when I click Edit button I do not see any delete (red color minus signs) for its cells so that I could select them to delete. 
The same works fine if I use UITableViewController. I have implemented following methods.

What am I missing that it does not behave the way it does when using standard UITableViewController?

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = !editing;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to switch `UITableView` to editing state:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```